# Android Google Task API - Interrupt chain

Tags: android, firebase, functional-programming, task

I'm using Firebase Auth API and Google play-services Task API.

I've this case, with a simple chain of tasks. I would to put this chain into a timeout case: for example, for poor connectivity, I would to stop the chain if are elapsed 5 seconds and the chain isn't completed.

I know the await() method, but it works on background and doesn't cancel right after a timeout period.

What is the best way to stop (or cancel) the chain? How can I re-schedule it?

```
    Task<Boolean> loginTask = delay(4000)
            .continueWithTask(task -> authManager.signInWithEmailAndPasswordTask("mymail", "mypass"))
            .continueWithTask(task -> setUserMailFirebase(task.getResult().getUser().getEmail()))
            .continueWithTask(task -> delay(4000))
            .continueWithTask(task -> setUserInfoFirebase())
            .continueWithTask(task -> delay(4000));

    loginTask.addOnSuccessListener(this, booleanTask -> goToActivity(true))
            .addOnFailureListener(this, booleanTask -> goToActivity(false));
```

Comment: Throw an exception from one of the tasks.

Comment: with throw new Exception() or TaskCompletionSource.setException? But if I throw an Exception on the setUserMailFirebase, the chain will be interrupted and will be called onFailureListener?

Comment: I suspect either one would work, depending on how you're implementing your tasks.  The point is that an exception should immediately propagate all the way up to the top task without allowing the others to run.

Comment: Hi Doug, I thought it was like that too. For example, If I have a custom task and if I set a TaskCompletionSource.setException, the next task will be executed with  a task.isSuccessfull() = false, so I have to check for each task if the previous has an exception.
I think that the best behaviour could be that the following tasks will not be executed, like in the Promises way.

Comment: You should be checking for errors in every task handler anyway.

Comment: Ok Doug, so the error spreads throughout the chain until the last onFailure. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, but remember to run it on a separate thread from loginTask

```
try {
    Tasks.await(loginTask, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    loginTask.setException(e);
}
```